# Java: initialize an inner class to get the data of it at the right position

Tags: java

I am parsing a message in the ShenzhenDecoder class - decode() method. After parsing it I am building the xml file in the ShenzhenRecoder class. But I am facing a problem to get the data out of the statusFlag class after setting the data in the ShenzhenDecoder class - assignStatusFlagMaptoRecorder(). Where and how have I to initialize the  inner StatusFlag class in the ShenzhenDecoder to get its data in side `createXMLFromRecord()`? since I am getting null for getStatusflag() and an exception for getStausFlag().getLowBattery() because getStatusflag() null is.

**ShenzhenDecoder**

public class ShenzhenDecoder {

```
ShenzhenRecord record = null;

LinkedHashMap<String, String> statusFlagMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();


public ShenzhenRecord decode(final byte[] data) {
        this.record = new ShenzhenRecord();
        byte[] imeiArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 1, 16);
        String imei = new String(imeiArray, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("IMEI: " + imei);
        this.record.setImei(imei);

}


private void assignStatusFlagMaptoRecorder() {
    StatusFlag statusFlagRecord = this.record.new StatusFlag();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : this.statusFlagMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        switch (key) {
        case "lowBattery":
            statusFlagRecord.setLowBattery(entry.getValue());
            break;
        case "spare1BitFirstByte":
            statusFlagRecord.setSpare1BitFirstByte(entry.getValue());
            break;

        case "lbs":
            statusFlagRecord.setLbs(entry.getValue());
            break;
        case "gmsBlindArea":
            statusFlagRecord.setGmsBlindArea(entry.getValue());
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

}

**Shenzhenrecord**

```
public class ShenzhenRecord {

    private String imei;
    private StatusFlag statusFlag;


    public String getImei() {
        return this.imei;
    }


    public void setImei(String imei) {
        this.imei = imei;
    }

    public class StatusFlag {

        private String lowBattery;


        public String getLowBattery() {
            return this.lowBattery;
        }


        public void setLowBattery(String lowBattery) {
            this.lowBattery = lowBattery;
        }

    }


    public Document createXMLFromRecord(String code) throws ApplicationException {

        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();

        Element shenzhenElement = document.addElement("shenzhen");

        shenzhenElement.addAttribute("imei", getImei());

        Element statusFlagElement = shenzhenElement.addElement("statusFlag");

        StatusFlag statusFlagtest = this.getStatusFlag();
        //Here I am getting an error because getStatusFlag() has null.
        String lowBatteryTest = this.getStatusFlag().getLowBattery();

        statusFlagElement.addAttribute("lowBattery", this.getStatusFlag().getLowBattery());

        }

    return document;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    StatusFlag statusFlagRecord = this.record.new StatusFlag();
```

means that the newly created StatusFlag has a reference to the record, not that the field 'ShenzhenRecord.statusFlag' is initialised. So just remove that line and let ShenzhenRecord initialize it's field itself as it's intended in OOP:

```
public class ShenzhenRecord {
    private String imei;
    private StatusFlag statusFlag = new StatusFlag(); 

    public String getImei() {
        return this.imei;
    }

    public void setImei(String imei) {
        this.imei = imei;
    }

    public static class StatusFlag {
```

And as long as inner classes don't need a reference to their surrounding class it might be a good idea to mark them as static. If you're interested in more flexible ways of initialising fields you could have a look on consturctors and initialisers.